# Conditionally skip mongoose hook function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a pre-save hook to encrypt `password` field of `User` schema, like:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
});

schema.pre('save', encrptPasswordHook);
schema.pre('update', encrptPasswordHook);
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', encrptPasswordHook);
...
```

By this way, I have encrypted password string in my database every time a `User` created or updated.

Now I have a JSON file of old `User` data with the encrypted password. I want to use this `User` model to import the JSON file into my database.

How can avoid the pre-save hook to encrypt the password again?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `User.collection.insert()` to bypass all Mongoose validations (the type of the inserted data won't be checked) and hooks, it uses the MongoDB driver directly:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string'
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

User.collection.insert({
    username: 'Some Name',
    password: 'The Encrypted Password'
});
```