# How to disable mongoose pre hook temporarily

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

in my mongoose Schema, I have the really useful `pre` hook configured to update the `lastModified` timestamp of my model.

```
var Document = new Schema({
  lastModified: {type: Date},
  title: {type: String, default: '', trim: true},
  ...
}
Document.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.lastModified = Date.now();
  next();
});
```

However, while we are upgrading to the new version, I need to modify certain fields of documents without changing the lastModified.

Is there a way to de-active the pre hook for a certain `save()` call or a better design instead of using pre for timestamp update?

Comment: moongose has timestamp option that you can enable when creating a Schema, `{timestamps: true}`. You can skip these timestamps or any hooks when saving if you directly use the underlying mongodb adapter when needed.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153998/conditionally-skip-mongoose-hook-function

Comment: Mongoose provides an option when updating to skip the timestamps as well. Then you can avoid using the native driver. Listed here as the second to last option. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update